# Bound on the Kolmogorov complexity of integers

Tags: logarithms, kolmogorov-complexity

I am reading *Elements of Information Theory* (Thomas M. Cover, Joy A. Thomas, 2nd edition) in which the following theorems are given (page 475--476):

1. For any integer $n$

$$ K(n) \leq \log^* n  + c. $$

2. There are an infinite number of integers such that $K(n) > \log n$.

Where $K(n)$ is the [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) of $n$ and $\log^* n$ is the [iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm) of $n$.

Assuming both statements true, this implis that there are an infinite number of integers $n$ such that

$$ \log n < \log^* n + c. $$

Knowing the growing rate of $\log$ and $\log^*$ this does not seem possible if $c$ is independent of $n$... Is it? If not, which one of the two above statements is false?

Comment: I'm not sure I see the issue. For any sufficiently large $n$, $\log^* n > \log n + \log \log n > \log n$. So wouldn't the inequality $\log n < \log^* n + c$ hold for any fixed $c$ as soon as $n$ is large enough?

Comment: @Artemy I don't see how $log^*  n > log n + log log n$ for sufficiently large n... Care to elaborate?

Comment: In Cover & Thomas, 2nd ed., p. 469, $\log^* n$ is defined as $\log n + \log \log n + \log \log \log n + ...$ (where only positive terms are kept).

Comment: @Artemy if this is the definition used in the book, them it would make sense. The Wikipedia definition is different thought, and I don't think they are equivalent (especially when looking at the value).

Comment: They are not equivalent, and yes, that is the definition used in the book (see p. 469).